# Запись в файл выполнения git pull при выполнении вручную на сервере происходит успешно, но при выполнении программой на сервере файл пуст

Tags: git, cmd

Есть сервер, на который надо автоматически выгружать свежую версию проекта. 
 
Вот примерный код программы, которая должна открыть командную строку и выполнить git pull:

```
public static void GitPull()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.Start();
        process.StandardInput.Write("E:\r\n");
        process.StandardInput.Write("cd /www/testsite/autotest\r\n");
        process.StandardInput.Write("git pull http://username:password@репозиторий master >> resultofgitpull.txt\r\n");
        process.StandardInput.Write("help >> testhelp.txt\r\n");
        process.Close();
    }
```

Если выполнять на сервере вручную команды из кода программы, то в файле resultofgitpull.txt есть данные о выполнении команды. 
Если выполнять программно, то файл создаётся, но он пуст.

 Почему такая разница и как узнать, почему git pull вручную выполняется, но автоматически изменений не делает и файл создаётся пустым?

Comment: В windows используется обратный слэш, а не прямой. `cd /www/testsite/autotest` точно работает в cmd?

Comment: а какая у вас конечная цель?

Comment: Такой слэш работает. Вручную, когда выполняла команды, просто копировала из кода. Конечная цель - автоматизированное тестирование.

Comment: А почему бы не написать один батник, который и запускать? Более того, этот батник можно и нагенерировать, запустит, а потом удалить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При выполнении вручную и выполнении программой пользователи разные. У одного прав хватало на выполнение и запись, у другого нет. Решила изменением пользователя в пуле на сервере.

Comment: Лучше бы вы пользователю пула права на папку дали.

Comment: На всякий случай, имя пользователя пула в свежих версиях винды - `IIS AppPool\{Имя пула}`. Еще можно использовать группу `IIS_IUSRS`